# How to do server paging in SQL correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My situation: My application is slow. As slow as it gets... mostly because I have the feeling my Server paging for my dataTables / grids are wrongly implemented.

Let's start:

- I have a SQL Server 2008 database, one table with all the information, 10 columns in it, at the moment 19K rows
- My application is based on a JavaScript and ASP.Net backend code.

My SQL query is:

```
WITH Ordered AS 
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created DESC) AS 'RowNumber'
      FROM Meetings
     WHERE State IN ('Appointed', 'Accepted')
       AND [xxx] LIKE '%1%'
       AND [yyy] LIKE '%2%'
) 
SELECT * 
  FROM Ordered
 WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 41;
```

So at the moment this query runs around 27 to 32 seconds, which means over 30 seconds I got a timeout... on 19k rows in 1 year... which means in 1 month latest every query will run against dead...

As far as I am understand the order for this query is the problem: No index done here. 
Because the query first sorts, then selects all with a manual row number, then selects only 40... (of course on page 2 of my grid it gets Rows 41 to 81...)

I *COULD* do an Index on my "Created desc" and the query would be much much faster, *BUT* every column is sortable for my grid which means "Created desc" could be *every* other column of my table and of course desc and asc order!

So, how to improve this?

//Edit:

Sorry to forget that:

The inner query (Inner Select) runs 6 seconds, while the total query runs 31 seconds... 
Which means the "WITH ORDERES AS" is the problem here!

Comment: You could potentially start by indexing State, [xxx] and [yyy], as they seem to be statically referenced?

Comment: Yeah, this 3 coloumns in the query are everytime the same (xxx, yyy and state)...

Comment: You are doing a wildcard search on both your columns `xxx` and `yyy`, so I think indexes on those 2 columns won't be used with this particular query. However, you might want to create indexes on columns which are likely to be used for filter/join/aggregation operations in general.

Comment: And thats my prolblem... my user can search and sort by every coloum of my grid and potential will...

Comment: The creation of the `ROW_NUMBER()` is your bottleneck, so adding an index on `Created` would speed up every query irrespective of what you filter on in your `WHERE` clause. Also, have you tried simply increasing the timeout from 30 seconds to 60?

Comment: Increasing the timeout is a not allowed solution from our IT here... again: Index on created would only speed up one query: that one, when the user sorts by created... so one of possible 20 kinds

Comment: Could you include an image of the actual execution plan taken that was taken for this query?

Comment: Also I think, what @shree.pat18 is mentioning is also pretty important, not so much, that you are doing a wildcard search, but that the wildcards are at the beginning also, is that really necessary? What kind of values are inside `xxx` and `yyy` that you want to capture?

Comment: Step 1: Use CTRL-L to observe the query plan and see if it suggests any indexes. Dynamic search columns and paging are always a problem. Is upgrading SQL Server an option? later versions have friendlier paging functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: you have a performance problem, approach it with a proper methodology and measure appropriately. *The inner query (Inner Select) runs 6 seconds, while the total query runs 31 seconds... Which means ...* is amateurism. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) for correct ways to measure performance. And before we continue, if you start from 6 seconds you have already lost the game.

Now, on to the question.

```
WHERE State in('Appointed','Accepted') AND  [xxx] LIKE '%1%' AND [yyy] LIKE '%2%'
```

This expression is basically non-indexable. Even if you add an index on `State` it will not help because of the low cardinality (few values with many rows each). And `like '% ... %'` is unindexable because it searches for values in the middle of the text.

You could try to replace `like '% ... %'` with a full-text search like [`CONTAINS ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) which will be faster, provider you search for specific enough terms. But it does require you to deploy and configure properly the [full-text indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

As for the paging, I do not favor much the `ROWNUMBER` approach. Even when a sort column exists, it involves a scan and count to skip the number of rows and gets slower and slower as you go to higher pages. I much more recommend the key based approach:

```
SELECT TOP (page size) ...
WHERE keys > <last row>
ORDER BY...
```

but this approach is more difficult to implement as it requires keeping track of *keys* rather than the page number.

But expect no miracles. You are asking a relational OLTP system to do the work of an ElasticSearch/Solr. It will never work as you expect. Use a tool appropriate for the job (a Search engine). Also read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) for a more thorough discussion, but again, expect no miracles.